# fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists

Tags: git, github, github-for-windows

I am trying to push files from my local machine to a remote server that is connected through LAN. I added a remote alias through the command:

```
$ git remote add testclient cq05.sabandtech.com:c/testforemotetransfer
```

I am getting an error like

```
$ git push testclient master
ssh: connect to host cq05.sabandtech.com port 22: Bad file number
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Still not able to solve this. I am not even able to connect via ssh from my local machine to the server. Assuming that ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com is the server on the network. When I ssh it via git bash:-
$ ssh -v ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com

I get the following error:-
OpenSSH_4.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8e 23 Feb 2007
debug1: Connecting to ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com [172.17.2.158] port 22.
debug1: connect to address 172.17.2.158 port 22: Connection refused
ssh: connect to host ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com port 22: Bad file number

It means that the two machines are not accessible through ssh.

I tried configuring the firewall of ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com by creating a new rule and allowing for port 22;still nothing happened.

When I tried connecting to ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com over https://;
git push https://ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com/e/projects2/testserver--where testserver is the git repository located in the e drive of the server;I get the following error:-

warning: push.default is unset; its implicit value is changing in
Git 2.0 from 'matching' to 'simple'. To squelch this message
and maintain the current behavior after the default changes, use:

git config --global push.default matching

To squelch this message and adopt the new behavior now, use:

git config --global push.default simple

See 'git help config' and search for 'push.default' for further information.
(the 'simple' mode was introduced in Git 1.7.11. Use the similar mode
'current' instead of 'simple' if you sometimes use older versions of Git)

fatal: unable to access 'https://ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com/e/projects2/testserver
/': Failed connect to ltpnaresh.sabandtech.com:443; No error

Please mind that I have already added the id_rsa.pub key in the authorized_keys of the server. Please help.

I am trying to connect two windows machines through gitextensions and trying to push files from one to another. Have already started git daemon on the server using [How to start git daemon on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5186070/how-to-start-git-daemon-on-windows)
The error I am getting is 
"fatal:  does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.  Please make sure you have the correct access rights and the repository exists."

Please help.

Comment: seems related to [this question on Super User](http://superuser.com/questions/256152/another-ssh-connect-to-host-github-com-port-22-bad-file-number)