# Why do git commands just return 'error: daemon terminated'

Tags: git, repository, git-daemon

I run `git add .` and then it does nothing for a while, and then says `error: daemon terminated`. This happens with all commands, not just `git add` How do I fix that? `git status` does show a bit of information about changes to be committed, but still shows the same error

Comment: There is no daemon involved with git commands like `add` or `status`. To unravel what's going on, you will probably need to include more about your environment / system. Something other than the usual git package must be involved here.

Comment: following your advice, simply uninstalling and reinstalling git fixed the issue

Comment: @LogosKing Well done. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: @DanLowe: there's a fancy new file system monitor that's intended to make Git go faster. For a long time it's been off by default, but it looks like it's now on by default on Windows. If it's misbehaving, the quickest thing is to just turn it off, since it's purely optional and is merely *intended* to make Git faster; whether it does, and if so how much, is another question entirely... :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is indeed a daemon starting with [Git 2.34 (Q4 2021)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69949221/6309), for the `fsmonitor`, using the [Simple-IPC protocol](https://git-scm.com/docs/api-simple-ipc#_simple_ipc_protocol).

Check the version of Git used and, in case this is is a bug, try and upgrade it to the latest 2.38.1.

(Which is closed to what the [OP Logos King](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13481325/logos-king) mentions [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74567291/why-do-git-commands-just-return-error-daemon-terminated?noredirect=1#comment131628964_74567291): "simply uninstalling and reinstalling git fixed the issue")

Check also the value of [`git config core.fsmonitor`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-corefsmonitor) (done from within your repository folder). Try and set it to `false` to see if the issue persists.