# git push windows to windows

Tags: git

I currently have a setup where on my windows machine with cygwin I added my linux server as a remote origin where I can then push my changes as I have my SSH keys configured.

```
git add remote origin ip@path.git
git push origin
```

How would I do this to my windows machine is it as simple as hosting an SSH server and if so which do you recommend?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It sounds as if you want be able to push to the repository on a Windows machine, so `git daemon` and the git protocol won't be enough for you.  If you need to be able to push to the repository you're left with these options:

1. Run an SSH server on your Windows box.  There are various guides you can find for doing this with Cygwin, e.g. [this one](http://therightstuff.de/2010/03/28/How-To-Set-Up-A-Git-Server-On-Windows-Using-Cygwin-And-Gitolite.aspx) or [this one](http://www.shannoncornish.com/blog/2009/04/git-server-windows-2008/).  An alternative is to use mSysGit, in which case you could chase the references in this Stack Overflow question: [Setup a Git server with msysgit on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1482824/setup-a-git-server-with-msysgit-on-windows)
2. Use git's "Smart HTTP" protocol - [sdorra's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189128/git-push-windows-to-windows/5193946#5193946) implies that SCM-manager lets you do this, but I've no experience of that.  However, Smart HTTP is essentially just provided by a binary called `git-http-backend` that you can use over CGI.  This binary is distributed in mSysGit, so you could set that up with a web server - for example, there's a tutorial on doing that with Apache [here](http://www.jeremyskinner.co.uk/2010/07/31/hosting-a-git-server-under-apache-on-windows/)

Another alternative is to mount your remote computer as a local drive and add it as a remote using the `file:` protocol.

Comment: The last alternative worked for me you mentioned. Mapping a drive to the Windows server (from a Mac), and then init a bare repo on the mapped windows drive ('git init --bare'), then saying "git remote add REMOTEBRNAME file://PATHTOMAPPEDDRIVE" on local repo. Works like a charm to 'git push REMOTEBRNAME', does as expected. Git deploy. Sweeeeeeeet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use git daemon. [Hosting Git Repository in Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/233421/hosting-git-repository-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

Or you could use [SCM-Manager](https://bitbucket.org/sdorra/scm-manager) and do the push or pull over http.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Gitblit](http://gitblit.com), an open-source, integrated, pure Java Git server, viewer, and repository manager for small workgroups. It works well on Windows and includes tools to run as a Windows service.