# Can one push to "git://" repo from Windows?

Tags: windows, git, git-push, git-daemon

I have a repo (on Linux machine), this repo is exposed by using `git://` protocol.
I can successfully clone, fetch and push to that repo from Linux machines.
But from Windows machines a can only clone and fetch from that repo.
When I am trying to push, the operation hangs, the last message from git daemon is
`Request receive-pack for '<my_repo_name>'`.

Is pushable `git://` protocol not implemented yet for using it from Windows?

Comment: Have you created an ssh key pair for your windows machine? You will need to do this to connect using ssh.
http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html#installing-ssh-keys

Comment: @iain - We don't need authentication (all computers in our LAN are friendly).  This is a test server just to learn git for git-newbies.  So, pure `git://` without ssh is enough.

Comment: I see here that git has a built-in protocol, interesting. So you should be able to push, if you are using the small git bash console, I would have thought that it will work if set up. Looks like you need to create a 'git-daemon-export-ok' file in the repo to do this, and will have to enable the push access.
https://git-scm.com/book/tr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols

Comment: @iain - I already have all that done. I can successfully do push from Lunux.  But for some reason it does not work from git-for-Windows.

Comment: Is this sounds like a windows/linux network issue, ssh is useing another protocol; I have heard that there are issues between netBEUI and linux. Sorry I cant be of much help here.
I did find this, it could give an idea as the answer seems relevant:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5189128/git-push-windows-to-windows

Comment: i am having same thing, try few version of git 2.23, 2.22, 2.08. all not working. linux to linux would work, windows to linux hang at push. any progress?

Comment: @pinky - No progress :-(