# TeamCity build labeling failing intermittently on a git repository

Tags: git, teamcity

My build is running on Windows Server 2003, TeamCity 6.0.3. The git repository is stored on the same server and is accessed via cygwin's sshd and gitd. My vcs configuration in TeamCity is as follows:

> Fetch URL: git://server/Repo
>
> Push URL: ssh://server/~/Repo
>
> Authentication settings
>
> Authentication Method: Password
>
> User name: TeamCitySC (this is a local account set up specifically for labeling)
>
> Password: * * * * * *

for each user there is a symlink in their home path to the Repository hence the ~/Repo path. Labeling worked just fine for about a 100 builds, recently it has periodically started to complain with the following message:

> Labeling failed for root 'git root'
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.JGitInternalException:
>   Updating the ref refs/tags/build-108
>   to 
>   Tag[03e70a74b39c1393f5ce684424194210513b4d48]={
>   object
>   0f6101df222f5370a17f5ce1c97eb2348d64970c
>   type commit tag build-108  tagger
>   PersonIdent[SYSTEM,
>   SYSTEM@server, Thu May 26
>   16:16:07 2011 -0600] } failed. 
>   ReturnCode from RefUpdate.update() was
>   REJECTED at
>   org.eclipse.jgit.api.TagCommand.call(TagCommand.java:159)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.buildTriggers.vcs.git.GitVcsSupport.label(GitVcsSupport.java:1334)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsLabeler.setLabel(VcsLabeler.java:80)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.vcs.impl.VcsLabeler.setLabel(VcsLabeler.java:1)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.FinishedBuildImpl.setLabel(FinishedBuildImpl.java:10)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.serverSide.impl.auth.SecuredBuildFactory$SecuredFinishedBuildImpl.setLabel(SecuredBuildFactory.java:3)
>   at
>   jetbrains.buildServer.controllers.SetLabelAction.doProcess(SetLabelAction.java:11)
>   at
>   etc...

It continues to fail even when I manually try to label the build via TeamCity (i.e. 'Label this build sources' link in the Changes tab for a given build).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the `ReturnCode REJECTED` in the error message it seems like your repository already has tag `refs/tags/build-108` and TeamCity does not force rewrite existing tag.

Comment: One would think so, but that is not the case.

Comment: Did you check repository on TeamCity machine? It could be found at one of subdirectories of `.BuildServer/system/caches/git`, it should be called something like `git-1E07B16A.git`. Once you find it, run command `git --git-dir=/full/path/to/.BuildServer/system/caches/git/you_repo.git tag`. Maybe tag was created only in TeamCity repository and wasn't pushed to your repository.

Comment: That's what it was, thanks. Still having an issue, but now it's giving me a git error, that I can troubleshoot

Comment: This could happen if you have several VCS roots for a single repository and some of them do labeling.

Comment: Using git to try and push the tags revealed my problem; permissions error in Stash on tags matching a pattern.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to TeamCity 6.5. It was released yesterday. We have had quite a lot of trouble with the DVCS functionality in 6.0.x. 6.5 is a great improvement. If the upgrade does not solve your issue, reply here. It made a lot of headaches for us go away. I'm not sure, but they may have dropped jgit. Seems that jgit has a lot of functionality missing and TeamCity has to work around those in the version you are using. Submodule support is one such feature.

I would also stay away from cygwin and go for the latest msysgit on the server. Cygwin also proved to be much more troublesome than msysgit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm going to try upgrading, but fwiw, we're only using cygwin for the ssh server and for installing a service that runs msysgit as a daemon as per [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233421/hosting-git-repository-in-windows)

Comment: have you looked at gitolite and hosting on a linux box? It works like a charm.