# Modifying existing built-in phone application

Tags: android, telephony, telephonymanager, rom

Instead of building my own custom telephony application by making use of the TelephonyManager class, is it possible to modify the built-in native phone application on a Google Nexus 4 or 5 device to make it do what I want?

Comment: There are thousands of Android devices, containing dozens, perhaps hundreds, of implementations of a "built-in native phone application". Most of those are proprietary, not open source.

Comment: Thanks... you say 'most'- what about any of the Google Nexus phones? Modified question to be more specific, please don't down vote!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the source code for the system apps (for example, the Dialer app is at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/packages/apps/Dialer/) and then modify it or use it as an example.

http://source.android.com/source/building.html might be useful to set up your dev environment to get the code.

Also, see [Download and modify android core apps in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6830573/download-and-modify-android-core-apps-in-eclipse)