# How to connect to a remote Git repository?

Tags: git, repository, git-remote

I am working with a team and we want to use Git (Not with GitHub, we have a private remote machine). We were using SVN until now.
We have a remote machine that works like an SVN repository.
Now, we want to turn this machine into the Git central repository.
By what I have read, what everyone needs to do on their machines, is to install Git and use the following command to add the remote main repository:

```
git remote add origin <remote_repo_url>
```

But what is the `remote_repo_url`? How can I figure it out?
Our remote machine has IP's like 189.14.666.666, in the remote machine I've installed Git and created a repository under C:\MY_GIT_REPOSITORY. What should I put in the URL on the local machines?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Now, if the repository is already existing on a remote machine, and you do not have anything locally, you do git clone  instead.

The URL format is simple, it is PROTOCOL:/[user@]remoteMachineAddress/path/to/repository.git

For example, cloning a repository on a machine to which you have SSH access using the "dev" user, residing in /srv/repositories/awesomeproject.git and that machine has the ip 10.11.12.13 you do:

```
git clone ssh://dev@10.11.12.13/srv/repositories/awesomeproject.git
```

Comment: In my case, I am using windows on the remote machine, and my repository is C:\MY_GIT_REPOSITORY (that was the folder were I executed the command "git init" through git console). What must I pu in the URL?

Comment: If the repository must be on windows (remote repositories should be created with git init --bare, by the way) then you could share the folder on the network and mount it locally and then do git clone, let's say it's mounted as /mnt/myawesomerepo you'd then do git clone /mnt/myawesomerepo, or if it's a windows machine, map as network drive (Z for example), and do git clone Z:/myawesomerepo, or setup a git daemon on the win machine as per: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/233421/hosting-git-repository-in-windows

Comment: And if i already have the project on my machine and just want to add the remote to push/pull commits? I do a `git remote add origin  Z:/myawesomerepo` ?

Comment: Yes, that would work, assuming that Z:/myawesomerepo is the path to the remote repository. (a windows/samba network share mapped to a drive letter)

Comment: What if we only  want to connect and see files name not Cloning the Project?

Comment: update answere: instead of only username@remote_server , you now have to additionally give your PAT

Answer (score 67):

It's simple and follow the small Steps to proceed:

- Install git on the remote server say some ec2 instance
- Now create a project folder `$mkdir project.git
- `$cd project and execute $git init --bare`

Let's say this project.git folder is present at your ip with address inside `home_folder/workspace/project.git`, forex- ec2 - /home/ubuntu/workspace/project.git

Now in your local machine, `$cd` into the project folder which you want to push to git execute the below commands:

- `git init .`
- `git remote add origin username@189.14.666.666:/home/ubuntu/workspace/project.git`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "Initial commit"`

Below is an optional command but found it has been suggested as i was working to setup the same thing

> git config --global remote.origin.receivepack "git receive-pack"

- `git pull origin master`
- `git push origin master`

This should work fine and will push the local code to the remote git repository.

To check the remote fetch url, `cd project_folder/.git` and `cat config`, this will give the remote url being used for pull and push operations.

You can also use an alternative way, after creating the `project.git` folder on git, clone the project and copy the entire content into that folder. Commit the changes and it should be the same way. While cloning make sure you have access or the key being is the secret key for the remote server being used for deployment.

Comment: Git requires me this command before push: `git push --set-upstream origin master`.

Answer (score 2):

**For Bitbucket repositories users**:

**Starting 01.03.2022** you need to generate app password:
https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/app-passwords/

You can choose what permissions you grant for this password during creation process.

Then connect by:

```
git remote add origin https://bitbucketusername:bitbucketAppPassword@bitbucket.org/your-team/your-repo.git/
```

Answer (score 1):

Like you said `remote_repo_url` is indeed the IP of the server, and yes it needs to be added on each PC, but it's easier to understand if you create the server first then ask each to clone it.

There's several ways to connect to the server, you can use ssh, http, or even a network drive, each has it's pros and cons.
You can refer to the [documentation](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols) about protocols and how to connect to the server

You can check the rest of [chapter 4](http://www.git-scm.com/book) for more detailed information, as it's talking about how to set up your own server

Answer (score 1):

To me it sounds like the simplest way to expose your git repository on the server (which seems to be a Windows machine) would be to share it as a network resource.

Right click the folder "MY_GIT_REPOSITORY" and select "Sharing". This will give you the ability to share your git repository as a network resource on your local network. Make sure you give the correct users the ability to write to that share (will be needed when you and your co-workers push to the repository).

The URL for the remote that you want to configure would probably end up looking something like
`file://\\\\189.14.666.666\MY_GIT_REPOSITORY`

If you wish to use any other protocol (e.g. HTTP, SSH) you'll have to install additional server software that includes servers for these protocols. In lieu of these the file sharing method is probably the easiest in your case right now.