# Issues hosting local git repo

Tags: git, cygwin, git-daemon

I've successfully set up a git repository with Cygwin on my desktop, thanks to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275844/3282436).

Now, I'm having problems connecting to that repo from my laptop.  Specifically, the connection times out every time.  I've even tried plugging the two computers into the same switch, but that hasn't helped.  Does anyone have any experience with this?  Perhaps it is some sort of firewall issue?

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the repo?

Comment: Through bash on my laptop (Fedora).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end, it was indeed a firewall issue.  In case anyone is interested, the port that you have to unblock is 9418.

I also had a couple issues because I accidentally typed `git clone git://[ip address]/RepoName **.git**` instead of simply `git clone git://[ip address]/RepoName`.

Hopefully that helps someone.