# Git how to access repository Windows local machine?

Tags: windows, git

I installed Git for Windows in order to clone and pull a project hosted on a remote Linux server.
In my repository (D:/repositories/my-project) I launch the following commands

```
git clone server@192.168.56.101:/var/www/web/my-project/.git

git pull origin master
```

So far so good. I pull the project files whenever modifications are applied on the server.
But now I'd like to pull or push from the remote server to my local repository.
I tried many things but I can't figure out how to access the repository located on my local machine.
Things like:

```
git pull duddy@my-pc:/d/repositories/my-project/.git master
```

just doesn't work, Git says:

> ssh: Could not resolve hostname my-pc: Name or service not known
>   fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Can someone helps me ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GIT clone repo across local file system in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2519933/git-clone-repo-across-local-file-system-in-windows)

Answer (score 0):

First things first, I would recommend you try simply running `git pull`.

If this doesn't work, try running `git remote -v` and check to make sure that the URL for your server is listed as an origin (server@192.168.56.101:/var/www/web/my-project/.git).

Your issue is that you are inputting the URL for your local repository in your attempt to `git pull`.

I suggest reading the [git-pull documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pull) to learn more about how pull works.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you need to have some service at your workstation which serves the requests. There are following options (I did not try most of them myself, just making it up from what I know):

1. use the windows file access. This is the easiest to setup at the windows workstation - just share the repository folder. The Linux side should somehow be able to mount windows shares (like described, for example, here: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently). If you manage to mount your `\\my-pc\repo` to some `/mount/my-pc-repo`, then you can access it as `file:///mount/my-pc-repo`.
2. run git daemon at windows. Set up instructions are available at SO (for example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/2275844/2303202) and it pretty straightforward, but it does not have any authentication and in most cases it is reasonable to use it only for reading, so you will not be able to push to the workstation, only fetch.
3. set up ssh daemon and access through ssh authentication with read-write access. Git for windows installation contains the needed software (the `sshd.exe` binary, it is there at least for Git for Windows 2.6.0), probably there is a way to utilize it but I could not find it quickly.
4. set up HTTP(S) service at your workstation. I don't know if it is possible to do only with Git for Windows (it might be, with some perl module which happen to be included with it), or you should use some other software.